# I am unable to configure views.py

Tags: django

Im using the official django tutorial and copy and pasting from there
and when I got to the bit about views and put it in my server started saying SyntaxError: invalid synytax

Ive already tried adding `url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote')`, instead of what i had.

```
File "/Users/Oisin/mysite/polls/urls.py", line 9
    url('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

so im meant to just get it to start up but instead im getting syntax error

Comment: What error do you get after adding the line that you have mentioned. And Can you also post what was the code which produced that error, ie urls.py

Comment: The problem is on the line before. Please show the full urls.py.

Comment: Did you put a `,`  at the end of the previous line in `urls.py ` if any?

Comment: my full urls.py is  from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$',views.index)
    # ex: /polls/5/
    url('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    url('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail')
```

instead of url(....).

I'm not sure but I think  url(...) is used when you need to use regex or Regular expressions.